# Incomplete hovering

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    ul {
      background-color: tomato;
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 20px;
      width: 50px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    a {
      color: white;
    }
    
    li:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: teal;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get hovering effect on say `home` element which correspondingly starts vertically above `home` element ( *** right*** from top of red box) to below(bottom of red box) , but as of now incomplete hovering is shown as per code snippet.

I seen some answers but cant understand and of course use flexbox but wanted to conceptually why this incomplete hovering happens and solution fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `teal` color on the hover state is covering the entirety of the `<li>` element as expected.  But that element has a `margin`.  A margin creates space *around* an element, not *within* an element.  That space around it does not change color with the hover effect.

You can replace the `margin` on the `<li>` with `padding` instead to add space *within* the element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    ul {
      background-color: tomato;
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 20px;
      width: 50px;
      padding: 10px; /* <--- here */
    }
    
    a {
      color: white;
    }
    
    li:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: teal;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: works great and answer accepted

Answer (score 1):

The incomplete hovering is happening because the background size of your element which is "ul" is more than your "li" element. Whenever we make this type of list we first create a "ul" element and then the "li" element so it's a subpart of the "ul".You need to mention the size of both elements and keep the size of li smaller than the ul element.

Hope this answers your question.